# Gii Unable to resolve the request "gii/index" -  merge array understanding

Tags: yii

Trying to access locally http://mysite.dev/gii but I'm getting:

> Gii Unable to resolve the request "gii/index"

Here is my **config/localdev.php** file:

```
'modules'=>array(
  // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool
  'gii'=>array(
     'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
      'password'=>false,
      // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only.
      'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
),
```

If I use this address:

http://mysite.dev/gii/default/login

But this a password protect one, and we defined as false.
We may think that localdev.php is NOT being applied, but I've echo "hello" inside the conditional that loads it, and it appeared".

Note:
Inside Yii framework there is a **.htaccess** file with:

```
deny from all
```

I don't see the reason for this behavior.

Can I have your help please ?

**Update regarding the comments:**

Here's the **localdev.php** requiring main.php

```
return CMap::mergeArray(
        require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/main.php'),
        array(
            'modules'=>array(
          'gii'=>array(
              'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
              'password'=>false,
              'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
        ),
         ),
```

Here's the URL on **main.php**

```
'components'=>array(
    'urlManager'=>array(
      'urlFormat'=>'path',
      'rules'=>array(
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>'=>'<controller>/index',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>'
       ),
      'showScriptName'=>false,
     ),
```

IF we should add those:

```
'rules'=>array(
  'gii'=>'gii',
  'gii/<controller:\w+>'=>'gii/<controller>',
  'gii/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'gii/<controller>/<action>',
```

Should I add this and place all that it's on **main.php** rules OR, can we precisely add just those rules here on **localdev.php** ?

Comment: If I should provide more details, like configuration files or .htaccess on public_html? I can provide those if needed.

Comment: Did you add the routes mentioned in the [manual](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii)?

Comment: @Jon care to have a look on my question update regarding your comment please ?

Comment: You can add that configuration too inside the array you are merging with `mergeArray` -- just be careful to get the correct structure.

Comment: @Jon but should I copy ALL rules array that is on main.php, or can I just place those "new lines" - bah... sorry... I may test this right a way... I will check. 2 min :)

Comment: @Jon - please correct me if am I wrong. Apparently, and unfortunately, we cannot add JUST those gii specific rules to localdev.php - We should take out the rules on main.php, and pass those to all other conf files we have.

Comment: I end up, replicating urlManager array on all configuration files (local, remove_dev, production), and change gii redirections accordingly. If you care to provide an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add the routes that service Gii to your app configuration as mentioned in the [manual](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii).